# TikZ: Paling Effect

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\def\cHeight{0.5}
\def\cWidth{4}
\newcommand{\cigarOne}[2]{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\result{\cWidth/2}
    \filldraw[pattern=north east lines] (#1,#2) rectangle (\result+#1,#2-\cHeight);
    \filldraw[pattern=crosshatch dots] (\result+#1,#2) rectangle (#1+\cWidth,#2-\cHeight);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \cigarOne{2}{5};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The command `cigarOne` defines two filled rectangles, and I want one of them (the left one) to be "pale", kind of hardly visible rectangle.

Comment: Did you already tried `semitransparent` or `opacity=<0..1>` on the `\filldraw? This makes it paler IMHO (but of course also partially transparent).

Comment: First, loading `tikz` is enough, it already loads `pgf` so you don't have to do that explicitly. Second, why are you loading so many libraries? You only need `patterns` for this example. Finally, does adding `opacity=0.1` to the options of the `\filldraw` you want to affect give the desired result? You can of course play with the value to get different opacity.

Comment: setting the opacity = 0.3 did yield kind of what I wanted, but is maybe the "blurring effect" is the best way to describe what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
%---------------------------------------------------------
\def\cHeight{0.5}
\def\cWidth{4}
\newcommand{\cigarOne}[2]{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\result{\cWidth/2}
    \filldraw[draw=black!10,pattern=north east lines,pattern color=black!10] (#1,#2) rectangle (\result+#1,#2-\cHeight);
    \filldraw[pattern=crosshatch dots] (\result+#1,#2) rectangle (#1+\cWidth,#2-\cHeight);
}
%---------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \cigarOne{2}{5};
\end{tikzpicture}
%---------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

[image]